# Finding the shortest distance between a 2D array of peaks

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to use MatLab to help in automated analysis of microscopy data from our lab. We have images that consist of 2D arrays of points that correspond to atom positions. We would first like to fit these positions to Gaussians, then find the shortest distance between the positions and draw vectors between them.

I've been using the [Fast 2D Peak Finder](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37388-fast-2d-peak-finder) to locate the peak positions and it works quite well. However, I'm having trouble identifying the shortest distances and plotting vectors between them. Does anyone have an idea for how this might work? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you simply want to find the shortest overall distance between any two peaks and plot a vector that connects them?

Comment: Are you also able to post some sample outputs from the Fast 2D Peak Finder to reproduce the input that you're getting? Perhaps also include a sample output that you expect?

Comment: @krisdestruction - The Fast 2D Peak Finder is probably one of the best submissions to FEX that I know.  It returns a `1 x 2N` vector with the `(x,y)` coordinates of each peak interleaved, so `[x1,y1,x2,y2,...xN,yN]` where `N` is the total number of peaks detected.

Comment: @rayryeng Not familiar with it, but I'll check it out if I ever have the need :)

Comment: @krisdestruction - Sounds good!  It's an awesome piece of code.

Comment: Thanks for your replies everyone. After thinking about it a bit more I believe that this is a really good start, but what would be quite valuable is the following.

Each point has four nearest neighbors around it. I'm thinking now to construct vectors between this point and the centroid of its four nearest neighbors. This would give me exactly what I need. Does anyone have any thoughts about how to approach this?

Comment: Also, here is exactly what I have in mind. [This](http://i.imgur.com/OdSg0BP.png) is the output I get from the 2D peak finder visualized as an image. My overall goal is to calculate vectors from each point to the centroid of the four nearest neighbors and overlay it as a vector like [this](http://i.imgur.com/jRovrH9.png) (I've only drawn a few vectors that aren't to scale to make it a little less confusing). Basically the idea is that each dot is displaced relative to the centroid of the four nearest neighbors and we'd really like to map this displacement.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you identify *n* peaks and store their coordinates in *n*-by-*2* matrix `X`, you could calculate the pairwise distance between these peaks using `D = pdist(X)` (this function requires the statistics toolbox).  By default, this will assume you are interested in finding the euclidean distance between each pair of point.

The returned vector, `D`, corresponds to a list of pairwise distances.  The [`pdist()` documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist.html) describes the meaning of the ordering of these distances.  I recommend following the `D = pdist(X)` with `D = squareform(D)` to convert the vector into a pairwise distance matrix.

Then you simply need to identify the shortest `k` distances you are interested in and plot these points.

I have provided an example way of doing this below.

```
X = rand(10,2); % Generate random 2D points
k = 3; % Number of closest pairs of points to choose
Y = [];

D = pdist(X); % Get vector of distances
B = sort(D,'ascend'); % Sort distances
D = tril(squareform(D)); % Convert distance vector to lower triangular matrix

% Find k pairs of rows of X corresponding to closest peaks
[Y(:,1),Y(:,2)] = find(ismember(D,B(1:k))); 

% Plot results
figure; hold on;
plot(X(:,1),X(:,2),'b+'); % Plot "peaks"
for i = 1:k
    plot(X([Y(i,1),Y(i,2)],1),X([Y(i,1),Y(i,2)],2),'r'); % Plot closest peaks
end
```

[image]